# if in_array in php and xml

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I have a long xml data file with 500+ items in it, it comes in this form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<CATALOG>
<ITEM>
    <TITLE>ITEM name</TITLE>
    <TYPE>"T1", "T2", "T3" </TYPE>
    <DESCIPTION>DESCIPTIONiliate Page CPM</DESCIPTION>
    <PRICE>PRICE</PRICE>
    <ITEM>http://mysite.com/item-link</ITEM>
</ITEM>
</CATALOG>
```

and I use the following code in the php page to import data from the xml file:

```
<?php
$ITEMSS = new SimpleXMLElement('ITEMS.xml', null, true);

echo <<<EOF
<table width="100%" align="center" border="1" bordercolor="#0099ff" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">

    <tr>
            <th bgcolor="#66ccff"><span class="style4">ITEM Name</span></th>
            <th bgcolor="#66ccff"><span class="style4">item TYPE </span></th>
            <th bgcolor="#66ccff"><span class="style4">item DESCIPTION </span></th>
            <th bgcolor="#66ccff"><span class="style4">item PRICE</span></th>
            <th bgcolor="#66ccff"><span class="style4">link to item</span></th>
    </tr>

EOF;
foreach($ITEMSS as $ITEMS) // loop through our DATAS
{
    echo <<<EOF
    <tr height="30" align=middle>
            <td><a href="{$ITEMS->ITEM}" target="_blank"><span class="STYLE7">{$ITEMS->TITLE}</span></a></td>
            <td><span class="STYLE8">{$ITEMS->TYPE}</span></td>
            <td><span class="STYLE8">{$ITEMS->DESCIPTION}</span></td>
            <td><span class="STYLE8">{$ITEMS->PRICE}</span></td>
            <td><a href="{$ITEMS->ITEM}" target="_blank"><B><span class="STYLE7">cHECK IT OUT</span></B></a></td>
    </tr>

EOF;
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

in the TYPE I have different values like:

```
    <TYPE>"T1", "T2", "T3" </TYPE>
    <TYPE>"T1", "T4", "T6" </TYPE>
    <TYPE>"T1", "T8", "T1" </TYPE>
```

each item may have diffrent TYPE values

I need to add an "if" statement in the loop to select only some data if a value is in array of TYPE  somethink like:

```
foreach($ITEMSS as $ITEMS) // loop through our DATAS
{
$options = array($ITEMS->TYPE);

if (in_array("T1", $options))

   { echo <<<EOF
    <tr height="30" align=middle>
            <td><a href="{$ITEMS->ITEM}" target="_blank"><span class="STYLE7">{$ITEMS->TITLE}</span></a></td>
            <td><span class="STYLE8">{$ITEMS->TYPE}</span></td>
            <td><span class="STYLE8">{$ITEMS->DESCIPTION}</span></td>
            <td><span class="STYLE8">{$ITEMS->PRICE}</span></td>
            <td><a href="{$ITEMS->ITEM}" target="_blank"><B><span class="STYLE7">cHECK IT OUT</span></B></a></td>
    </tr>


EOF;
}

}
```

but even if the value I look for is in the array , it shows nothing!.

So how can I use if in array statement in this case?

Comment: With `"value I want"`, can you give an example of exactly what you would have there?

Comment: That is not an array but a string, so `in_array` does not make much sense. Better isolate the problem first, your question will be much better and you will solve it faster.

Comment: the Value I want can be T1 , T2 ..., I want to show on a page data that have T1 in TYPE  and in other page data that have T3 in TYPE for example

Comment: @hakra , what do you mean? so how to use if statement to check if a value exists in a given list of TYPE ?

Comment: Please add the output of `var_dump($ITEMS->TYPE);` to your question.

Comment: @hakra , where can I do that?

Comment: Before that line `$options = array($ITEMS->TYPE);` and you then need to locate the output in the HTML sourcecode within your browser.

Comment: @hakra , when I add thta it shows: "object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) { [0]=> string(13) "T1, T2, T3" } "

Comment: And you now want to find out if, for example, T2 is in that comma separated list?

Comment: Alright, you find an answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12545786/367456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from your preparation of the $options variable, try initiating it like so;

PHP >= 5.3

```
$options = array_map(function($type) {
    return str_replace('"', '', trim($type));
}, explode(',', $ITEMS->TYPE));
```

PHP < 5.3 (put the function out of the loop :D)

```
function parseTypes($type) {
    return str_replace('"', '', trim($type));
}

$options = array_map(parseTypes, explode(',', $ITEMS->TYPE));
```

That should explode the types into an array, remove the quotes and trim extra spaces.

Comment: I got this error: " unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in line" and that line is for "$options = array_map(function($type) {
"

Comment: Added a < 5.3 example for use without closures

Comment: thank you so much Jason Brumwell, it was perfect , I have php 5.2.17 , that's why it wouldn't work :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of placing an `if` clause inside the `foreach` loop, you just pass another list into the `foreach`, one that only contains the elements you are looking for. Works like magic, actually this is called *xpath*:

```
$value = 'T1';
$list  = $ITEMSS->xpath('/CATALOG/ITEM[contains(TYPE, \'"' . $value . '"\')]');
foreach($list as $ITEMS)
{
    ...
```

And that's it. This works because each value you might want to look for is enclosed in double quotes `"`, a common principle.

BTW, I think your code would profit a lot from a simple template engine, like for example [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/). It works as well with iterators (a list of values you iterate over with `foreach`).